# angularjs change service property from $http.get

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

The following code should check if a user is logged in and "save" the response in the accountService.

The commented line (`//accountService.currentUser = {username : 'test'};`) worked but as soon as i alter the service property from within the $http callback it doesn't work. So what am I missing?

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/portal/index.html',
        resolve: {
            loggedin: isLoggedIn
        }
    })

    var isLoggedIn = function($q, $timeout, $http, $location, accountService){ 
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        //accountService.currentUser = {username : 'test'};
        $http.get('/api/account/isLoggedIn').success(function(user){ 
            if (user) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    accountService.currentUser = user;
                    deferred.resolve();
                }, 0); 
            } else { 
                accountService.currentUser = null;
                $timeout(deferred.reject, 0);
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: what is output of `user` when you wrote: `accountService.currentUser = user;`

Comment: why don't you move the whole isLoggedIn function into accountService and just inject accountService to app.config -> resolve: {loggedin: accountService.isLoggedIn }

Comment: @doodeec i thought i can only inject providers and no services to app.config?

Comment: @MaximShoustin the directive which does use accountService doesn't get updated and simply thinks the user is still null

Comment: @kannix I'm not sure about if it is possible, it's just a thought... anyway, why are you even doing all of this in config and not in appRun or a controller?

Comment: @doodeec i think setting up the $routeProvider should be done in config? Do you have any tutorial or link about using appRun for this?

Comment: @kannix yes, but why to do all the logic for loggedin in config? What is the point of having the loggedin when you are defining the route?

Comment: @doodeec i did that just for simplicity i'll put that in a provider but even then i guess i'll have the same problem ;)

Comment: @kannix and what about setting the loggedIn variable as the first thing to do in the controller... I suppose you won't need it sooner anyway

Comment: @doodeec the idea is that if you call the / route and are not logged in you get redirected to /login however if you are logged in you get to the / site thats why i'm doing it in the routeProvider

Comment: @kannix you can do it the same the way I did - register login.html as '/' route, and make the loggedin check and redirecting inside login controller. It's fast so you won't see a difference